# Dictating in unsupported applications with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13 without going through the dictation box

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Unlike Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5, there was an option not to use the dictation box if the application I was dictating into was not supported by Dragon. In Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13, this option has disappeared.

Is there any way to dictate in an unsupported application without going through the dictation box with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13?

Answer (score 3):

I just got Dragon 13 and was wondering the same thing. I found it under Tools > Options > Miscellaneous:

[image]